# How can I map this navigation property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I have two collections.  The parent has many children, but also stores the most current child's id.

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public int? CurrentBarId { get; set; }

    // adding this causes the error below
    public virtual CurrentBar CurrentBar { get; set; } 
}

public class Bar 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

When I add the CurrentBarId property everything is persisted correctly.  However, when I add the CurrentBar property an exception is thrown when the *Bar* is created.

I get the exception:

```
{"Invalid column name 'Foo_Id'."}
```

How can I map this navigation property in the context?

**Update**

I have played around with this a bit and ended up with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.CurrentBar)
    .WithOptionalDependent()
    .Map(map =>
    {
        map.ToTable("Bar").MapKey("CurrentBarId");
    });
```

Now I get the following error.  Is this in the right direction, or how should I be trying to do this?

> error 3034: Problem in mapping
>   fragments starting at lines 213,
>   442:An entity from one EntitySet is
>   mapped to a row that is also mapped to
>   an entity from another EntitySet with
>   possibly different key. Ensure these
>   two mapping fragments do not map two
>   unrelated EntitySets to two
>   overlapping groups of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Foo.Bars` and `Bar.Foo` are the ends of the same relationship and that `CurrentBar` is one end of a second relationship, I would try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasMany(f => f.Bars)
    .WithRequired(b => b.Foo)
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.FooId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.CurrentBar)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.CurrentBarId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This will create a (nullable) `CurrentBarId` FK column in the `Foos` table and a (not nullable) `FooId` FK column in the `Bars` table.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think to use HasMany.  It looks like it worked, thanks a bunch!